# Mapping IP address to cities speedily

Tags: amazon-redshift, ip-address, derived-table

I have an events table that includes a column for IP address.  I also have a mapping table that takes 0-padded IP address ranges and has a corresponding city, country.

I can write the query that converts an IP address to a 0-padded IP address, and then joins against my mapping table.

But performance-wise, I can't get anything to work.  The events table is 40m+ rows, so trying a join based on a field manipulation takes 30 minutes before I pull the plug.  I tried mapping a mapping table (IP to 0-padded IP) but it did not improve things.  Even building a reduced table of unique IP addresses with city is taking forever.

Is there an approach or strategy I should take here to try to get merge these datasets more efficiently?

Comment: do you have an index on each table

Comment: No, Redshift doesn't support indexes.  I did try putting IPs as sortkey and distkey, but still takes too long

Comment: what is size of data..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do this on the fly every time. A good approach is to materialize. Especially since your data is likely immutable (IP is not changed once it's recorded for whatever data is in the row), you have more options. They can be:

1. run a script every night to rerun the whole join
2. run incremental appends, so  every new portion of data, append the join for every new portion of data that comes into the source table

If you can afford storing another copy of 40m+ table you can just store the result as a new table that has all columns from the source table plus county (and maybe 0-padded IP), if not you can store a table with some ID from the source table plus join results that provides a faster join than the original query.
Or maybe if the source table is a result of some ETL/ELT process that can just be another step.